# react native images not shown after building apk

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I know this is a common know issue, but still no answwer as solved my problem.
In my react native projet i have a folder 'pages' in which i store the js files for the pages to be shown. In this pages I whant to use images from a folder 'assets/images'.
When I run it locally on a virtual device it works perfectly, but whenever I generate the apk and intall it on my device the images disappear.

[image]

Any help?

Comment: what it's IMAGE_NAME?
BTW, please post code in text, no images.

Comment: I used IMAGE_NAME as it was a resolution to the problem, basically creating a index.js file with:
export const IMAGENAME = require('./causasAgitacaoPsicomotora.png');

Comment: this was just a try at solving it, the initial intent I had was to use the images in /assets/images

Comment: don't mind the IMAGE_NAME if you have any solution

Comment: How did you generate the APK ?

Comment: I'm using the command: exp build:android